# I am trying to have a vertical tab with hidden content

Tags: craft3

In Craft 3, I am trying to build a vertical tab categories using href=#sample and the hidden content id=sample. I am using bootstrap JS as my library. Here is the code I use. I somehow not managed to hide my content, as the method I am using is if and else. Does anyone have any idea? I'm using `entry.title` for both the href and id. Ignore the `onclick`, I was trying out something with it.

```
<div class="row">
                                    
    <div class="col-lg-4">
                              
        <div class="list-group" id="list-tab" role="tablist">
            {% for entry in entries %}
                <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action {% if entry.id == page.id %} active {% else %} !active {% endif %}" id = "{{entry.title}}-list" role="tab" aria-controls="home" href="#{{entry.title}}" onclick ="">{{entry.title}}</a>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
                            
        <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
            {% for entry in entries %}
                {% set thumb = entry.singleImage.first() %}

                <div class="tab-pane {% if siteMainUrl.text  == href %} active {% else %} hide {% endif %}" id="{{entry.title}}" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="{{entry.title}}-list" onclick="">                                         
                    <h2 style="color:#fcc61e;">{{entry.text}}</h2>
                    <img src="{{ thumb.getUrl('categories')|default(fallbackImage.getUrl('fallbackImage')) }}" width="{{ thumb.getWidth('categories') }}" height="{{ thumb.getHeight('categories') }}" alt="{{ entry.title }}" title="{{ entry.title }}">
                    <a class = "btn-lg btn-default btn" href= "{% if entry.linkurl is empty %}javascript: void(0);{% else %}{{ entry.linkurl }}{% endif %}">Click Here</a>                  
                </div>
            {% endfor %}                                        
        </div>
                                                                
    </div>
                                    
</div>
```

The problem with this method is that instead of showing one tab-content per href, it is showing all.

Answer (score 1):

You might be better using entry.slug instead of entry.title as there could be spaces in the title.
Or add a filter to the title - e.g. entry.title|kebab  which would remove any spaces.

Also this line:

```
{% if siteMainUrl.text  == href %} active {% else %} hide {% endif %}
```

Where is href coming from? Is it to have a different active tab to the initial one?

Typically I use:

```
{% for item in tabdata %}
   <div class="tab-pane fade {{ loop.index == 1 ? 'show active' }}" id="{{ item.title|kebab }}" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-{{ item.title|kebab }}-tab">

  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Which leaves the first tab active.